# When given a named anchor (#comments), make the page jump to 30px lower than the actual anchor

Tags: html, css, anchor

Is this possible without using jQuery or javascript? I've tried to relatively position the anchor tag, and then use top: -30px, but that doesn't seem to matter. The page always jumps to where the anchor mark-up is rendered, not to where CSS moves it. Any suggestions?

The solution:

Put the link inside of the element you're targeting. In the parent element (position:relative), on the named anchor (position:absolute; top:-30px). Works like a charm.

Comment: may be live example is better

Comment: I wish I could, but this is on a sandbox environment. Imagine this code: `<ul><li><a name="comment1"></a>blah</li><li><a name="comment2"></a>blah</li><li><a name="comment3"></a>blah</li></ul>`. Each list item is styled so they're right on top of each other. I need a way to make #comment2 jump to the correct spot, only 30px higher on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just put some padding at the top of the element that contains the anchor link id?
I just tried it and it seems to work.

css:

```
h2 {padding-top:50px;}
```

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#here">Here</a></li>
</ul>

<h2 id="here">Title</h2>
<p>blah blah</p>
```

Comment: I could, but that completely breaks the design. Everything is butted against each other, and there is no room for additional padding or margin.

Comment: this is probably a bad solution but you could put the id="here" on some element above that actual/original element.

Comment: Thought about that... not feasible.

Comment: I don't understand your example...on top of eachother and 30px higher? From your example code is comment#2 the only one that is 30 pixels higher? Or are you trying to make it pop up when you click the anchor link?

Comment: No, #comment2 was just an example. All three would need to jump to the named anchor location, but 30px higher. I figured it out and edited the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use something simple like:

```
    ul > li > a {
        position: relative;
        top: -30px;
    }
```

That'll make your anchors appear 30px above without altering the rest of your layout. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/TU7CH/)

I've added the numbers just so you can see what it's doing, of course a little trial and error maybe needed but it should do the trick I imagine.